# C program rearrange checkers

Tags: c, sorting, math, puzzle

I was trying to see if I could code this math puzzle called moving checkers into C program. Say we have 4 empty spots,and 6 checkers alternating black and white
Such as this 0,0,0,0,b,w,b,w,b,w

Now you are allowed to only move checkers in pairs. 2 at a time, sliding them to vacant place, and you can't disturb their order. The book showed this done in 3 steps such as below.

0,0,0,0,b,w,b,w,b,w start

0,0,w,b,b,0,0,w,b,w first pass

0,0,w,b,b,b,w,w,0,0 second pass

w,w,w,b,b,b,0,0,0,0 third pass

I've looked at algorithms such as merge sort, and bubble sort. But they don't seem like what would work for me to code something to solve this problem.

I've though about putting this into an array. Running a for loop from 4-9 since these aren't empty. Comparing the right and left, and then having logic to move it. But am stumped on how to implement this in C code. The for loop and comparisons aren't a problem. It's the logic on moving them until I get three white pieces at the start.

Comment: "But am stumped on how to implement this in C code" --> post what you have tried.

Comment: have you tried all other sorting algorithms ?

Comment: The artificial requirement (only move two checkers in pairs) prevents the application of any general-purpose sorting algorithm. You need to implement your own. Show us what you have, and where specifically you stumble.

Comment: Use   [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to write your code. Use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile it. Use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug your code and understand its behavior. Consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop: it provides `gcc`, `emacs`, `gdb` .... Try also [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) and the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your code. Take inspiration from *existing* source code on [github](https://github.com/)

Comment: For your next question, please provide some [mre]. And read [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One comment was right, there is no generic sorting algorithm, later you'll see the problem is the missing strict order.
So lets try do design one from scratch. This answer is not intended to be complete, just ideas on how to approach such a problem.

Since your code snippet is the implementation of an already known approach, it won't help much.
So lets start:
Your first approach should not mind runtime complexity, but get the right objects. And we try to generalize.
It was already commented that the double-element swapping is the key.
So having 9(n) element make it n-1 pairs. These are ordered pairs of the alphabet you have.
These are `00 0w 0b w0 ww wb b0 bw bb`,
it might be helpful to give them new names, like
`A B C D E F G H I`
mathematical they are identical with some restrictions on the second version:
A can only be follwed by B and C and so on.
You can just write two methods for translating them. All operations to swap and check will be done on this version.

And here is the Problem of the missing order obviuos: like there is no answer to which is greater/smaller for e.g. D and G and there is no value in it for the problem with a sorting algorithm. Maybe there is later.

Swapping: one must be `A=00` and the other one must be more than 1 Index away from that. This makes it easy to identify one side of the swap-indices (cold be at max 2 elements) (or on equalized distribution floor(n/3))
After a swap the neighbor-Elements change their value!

Where we want to go: we need somewhere the sequence `www` means one must be E and an additional w, so we need to look for `BE, ED, EF, HE`
,generalized `BE..E, E..ED, E..EF, HE..E`

So to the core algorithm: Think one step at a time, meaning somewhat recursive. From that we can check the tree of opportunities*. We are at a dead end when there is no `A` anymore (no place to swap) so we stop the recursion or we found a solution `www` if we only look for one solution, otherwise attach the path in that tree to the solutions list until you have enough.
So iterate over all `A`s and then the remaining indices one index away from it.
Each Iteration will have the parameters swap-index of the A (a), the other swap-index (i) and your Array T

Normally you'll now look for patterns and opportunities to chance in the recursive tree:

First: swapping will never destroy an A, so there will be always an opportunity to go on, but: the new swap pair must not be the old one (which would just go back in the tree). The traversion will not end (since there is always an A), so no direct recursion call or at least a breaking condition by the recursion depth. One could creating a task-list of ways through the tree that must be checked, each element contains either `(a,i,T)` or a sequence `[(a0,i0),...,(an,in)]` and your recusive call is replaced by an append of this element to the list.

Second: the patterns in the changing neighbors: If one wants to create `E`s there are ways towards them(just check what ways combines to `ww`) these are the primary candidates for swapping, and the nearer they are, the more they should be prefered. Since these ways are limited they repeat once in a while. With that pattern the options for swapping reduces massively. These patterns can then also be replaced by sequences of your new alphabet. So then you look for triplets, like 'BAH' and 'CDC' that change to new triplets when swapping their inner letter. This can be tabluated and this table then can be rated, ordered and this order needs to be applied when checking.

Since you asked directly for a mathematical or algorithmic way on how to handle such problems this should be a way on ho to look on things. Generally: take the time to give your structures names. Or when it comes to programming, I think it was Stroustrup who once said: If you can think about it, make it a class!

*to all that like to comment: bruteforce... exponential complexity yadda yadda, Im totally aware of it, this is the design step!

Comment: btw: your first loop don't loop: `for(a=4;a>9;a++)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code so far below. The while loop doesn't output anything anymore

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    char checkers[10] = {0,0,0,0,'b','w','b','w','b','w'};
    int a,temp1,temp2,cntr;
    cntr = 1;
    int i;
    //check each value right and left adjacent
    printf("%d a position",a);
    while(!(checkers[0] == 'w') && !(checkers[1] == 'w') && !(checkers[2] == 'w'))
    {
        for(a=4;a>9;a++){
            // if 3 white in a row followed by 3 black in a row done and exit
            printf("%d a position\n",a);
            if(checkers[0] == 'w' && checkers[1] == 'w' && checkers[2] == 'w' && checkers[3] == 'b' && checkers[4] == 'b' && checkers[5] == 'b')
            {
                printf("workd");
                for(i=0;i<(sizeof(checkers)/sizeof (checkers[0]));i++)
                {
                    printf("Checkers have finished being moved result is:%c",checkers[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //once w and b found move it to empty space 2 and 3
            if(checkers[a-1] == 'b' && checkers[a+1] == 'b')
            {
            //check if 2-3 position is empty
                if(checkers[1] == 0 && checkers[2] == 0)
                {
                    temp1 = checkers[a];
                    temp2 = checkers[a+1];
                    checkers[cntr] = temp1;
                    checkers[cntr+1] = temp2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        // looking for b followed by w, checking if 6 and 7th spot is empty
        // then moving it into that spot
            if(checkers[a-1] == 'w' && checkers[a+1] == 'w' && checkers[2] == 'b' && checkers[5] && checkers[6] == 0)
            {
                temp1 = checkers[a];
                temp2 = checkers[a+1];
                checkers[5] = temp1;
                checkers[6] = temp2;
                // move 2 and 3 down one
                temp1 = checkers[1];
                temp2 = checkers[2];
                checkers[2+1] = temp1;
                checkers[1+1] = temp2;
                // finally move two whites to the front
                temp1 = checkers[8];
                temp2 = checkers[9];
                checkers[0] = temp1;
                checkers[1] = temp2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
/*
just shows what swapping looks like
{0,0,0,0,b,w,b,w,b,w};
{0,w,b,0,b,0,0,w,b,w};
{0,w,b,0,b,b,w,w,0,0};
{0,0,w,b,b,b,w,w,0,0};
*/
```

I'm doing a bunch of moving and it should eventually get to be put in correct. What I am stumped on is that there probably is some mathematical way and algorithm to solve these kind of problems. So was wondering how it would work in code. My code is arranging it based on what i've already figured out, to make it match. What if amount of empty spaces changes at the start or more pieces get added? I've looked into heap permutation sort, and bubble sort, but it's showing one item at a time being moved in examples.